# Why do I see a performance boost when creating mockito mocks inline?

Tags: android, performance, unit-testing, junit, mockito

When using mockito 2, I see a huge performance boost when instantiating mocks inline vs using @Mock annotations or instantiating them in the setup method. This is super confusing to me because nowhere in the documentation is discouraged to instantiate mocks inline, despite the apparent performance boost. All times were taken from Android studio's test runner output that displays execution time.

I created a new project with a very simple test:

```
    private val mockBanana: Banana

    private lateinit var cut: Person

    @Before
    fun setup(){
        cut = Person()
    }

    @Test
    fun check(){
        cut.banana = mockBanana

        cut.eat()

        verify(mockBanana).grow()
        verify(mockBanana).harvest()
        verify(mockBanana).peelOff()
        verify(mockBanana).eat()

    }
```

Then, I just changed the way the mock is created.

Slow method: call mock in setup. Takes 400ms

```
    @Before
    fun setup(){
        mockBanana = mock(Banana::class.java)
        cut = Person()
    }
```

Slow method: mock annotation. Takes 430ms

```
    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockBanana: Banana
```

Fast method: calling mock inline. Takes 25ms

```
    private val mockBanana: Banana = mock(Banana::class.java)
```

Initially I thought the performance boost was caused by the mocks only being created once per class and then shared between all tests, which would be a deal breaker. However, further testing showed without a doubt that that wasn't the cause (I used breakpoints and logs in the mockito code and the mocks were created multiple times. Also, the mock reference is always different between tests).

Before I start the huge endeavour it would be to refactor all the tests in my project, I'd like to understand the performance boost a little bit better to ensure nothing will break in the future.

Comment: You might want to include how you measured these times. Microbenchmarking is quite difficult to do correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the "performance increase" was just android studio being misleading with test execution times. I used JProfiler and saw that both inlining the method call and doing it in the setup method leads to a call to `Mockito.mock()` that takes the same time to execute. The only difference is where in the stack trace said call is performed, so I'm assuming android studio only starts counting after a certain point, which leads to the very low execution times.

I also double checked using gradle's built in profiler and observed the same results. Regardless of mock initialisation method, the test execution takes the same amount of time.